# Win10 UWP Custom Video Effect, IBasicVideoEffect 2019

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Actually I have the same problem than this one: [Win10 UWP Custom Video Effect, IBasicVideoEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079858/win10-uwp-custom-video-effect-ibasicvideoeffect/32147340) but the accepted answer did not help me, maybe its no longer valid today. Stackoverflow hints I should not ask questions there so here goes a new question.

I managed to get a working `IBasicVideoEffect` running in a Windows 10 UWP app. Its already in a separate WinRt component.

The next step would be to cast the `IMediaExtension` object resulting from `mediaCapture.AddVideoEffectAsync` to its orignial class but even casting to `IBasicVideoEffect` results in 'unable to cast object of type System.ComObject to type IBasicVideoEffect'.

Without casting everything works as expected. Built in effects like `Windows.Media.Core.FaceDetectionEffect` are castable, seems like I am missing something on my custom effect. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please refer this [blog](https://english.r2d2rigo.es/2016/03/10/creating-custom-video-effects-in-uwp-apps/).

Comment: Thanks for the link! Sadly it does not contain any new information. My question is not how to create a new effect, thats done already.

Comment: I will the check latest document , if i find some new i will share with you.